# Is it possible to boot faster with Windows 8.1 when dual booted with Ubuntu (14.04)?

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

Is it possible to boot faster with Windows 8.1 when dual booted with Ubuntu (14.04)?

I am familiar of fast boot being disabled during installation of Ubuntu.  Does that mean Windows will always boot slower now? I even tried  setting default boot to Windows 8.1.

Else, can I at least choose which OS should be booting fast?

Right now Windows is the default OS on grub, but still Ubuntu is booting quicker than Windows.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Window 8 "Fast Boot" feature is not actually boot at all. It is hibernation.

When you install Ubuntu it is recommended to disable fast boot in Windows, because if Windows is hibernated, you can not mount Windows partitions with read/write capabilities in Ubuntu.

You can enable fast boot in Windows, if you do not use NTFS partitions in Ubuntu or use them in read only mode.

But Ubuntu just really boots fast. If you want a faster startup in Ubuntu, you can enable hibernation there as well.

Comment: even with fast boot disabled it still hangs the mounted drives.

Comment: What do you mean by "hangs the mounted drives"? And what is "it"?

Comment: Windows will still refuse to unmount the drives unless you reboot.

Comment: Windows does not have "mount" feature at all. What are you talking about? Do you mean that you can not mount Windows drives in Ubuntu? That means that Windows is not shut down properly, but it is hibernated.

Comment: yes Windows does have a mount feature, it called mount everything in sight.

Comment: And what "fast boot" are you talking about? In Windows or in bios? Either way you can turn fast boot on.

Comment: @Pilot6,  What do you mean by using NTFS partitions in Ubuntu? I am new at this.  I removed 20gb from a hard drive by shrinking volume. And while installing I created partitions. (2 gb for swap area and the rest for journaling space).  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Jack I mean that normally you can read/write from/to NTFS partitions from Ubuntu. But if Windows is hibernated, you can mount these only in read-only mode.